# react-native: firestore - How to get folder names from storage bucket ref?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

If I need to get images urls from folders then I do the following:

```
const ref = storage().ref('foldername');
ref
    .listAll()
    .then(function (result) {
      result.items.forEach(function (imageRef) {
        // And finally display them
        displayImage(imageRef);
      });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      // Handle any errors
    });

  function displayImage(imageRef) {
    imageRef
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(function (url) {
        // TODO: Display the image on the UI

        console.log('urlurlurlurl', url);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // Handle any errors
      });
  }
```

but I need to get list of folder names first to show their names in application.

for example -
my storage bucket contains 3 folders. each folder contains 5 images.

I need to get list of these 3 folders first.

I am trying to find an answer [here](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/storage/reference#getDownloadURL) but not able to find it.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Here is my bucket with 2 directories. these 2 directories has images files
[image]

I need to get these directory names first so I can show them on screen. then I will fetch files based on directory selection from client.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, your code is only looking at files with the given prefix by iterating `result.items`:

```
ref
    .listAll()
    .then(function (result) {
      result.items.forEach(function (imageRef) {
        // And finally display them
        displayImage(imageRef);
      });
    })
```

If you want to know the names of nested prefixes (what you call "folders"), you will have to iterate `result.prefixes` as well.  The React Native documentation doesn't seem to provide an example of this, but you can see it in the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files).

```
ref
    .listAll()
    .then(function (result) {
      result.items.forEach(function (imageRef) {
        // ...
      });
      result.prefixes.forEach(function (folderRef) {
        // ...
      });
    })
```

Comment: it shows me empty array for prefixes. also when I do result.prefixes it means I will have to give folder path to get the result ? is there a way to get all folder names from the bucket ?

Comment: I don't know.  I can't see the data in your bucket.  That's the only way I would know if your code might not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to access the files' names as I was trying the same thing:

Use refFromURL to create a reference to the URL, then access ".name" from the URL reference.

`console.log("FILE NAME" + fileName);`

should return on the filenames in the folder in YOUR PATH.

```
const getNewImages = () => {
    
    const listRef = storageRef.child("YOUR/PATH");
  
    // Find all the prefixes and items.
    listRef
      .listAll()
      .then((res) => {
    
        
        res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
          
          let urlRef = storage.refFromURL(itemRef);
          let fileName = urlRef.name;
          console.log("FILE NAME" + fileName);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERROR" + error);
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
      });
  };
```